# How do C++ compilers distingush between shift bits left / shift bits right and ostream<< / ostream>> operators?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, operators, ostream

I was just writing some code to spit out a wave header. I started typing this:

```
file << 0x52 << 0x49 << 0x46 << 0x46 << ...
```

This made me think: How does a compiler tell the difference between interpreting the above as this:

```
file << 0x52; file << 0x49; file << 0x46; file << 0x46;
```

... and this:

```
file << (0x52 << 0x49 << 0x46 << 0x46);
```

And of course, all permutations/combinations of possibilities of these operators.

My guess is that the compiler somehow knows that the first is correct and the second is wrong, but what rules is it following?

Comment: C doesn't have operator overloading, so there is no need to distinguish; for C++, it's the same as with other overloads of operators.

Comment: @mafso Oops, yes of course. What's the rules for the other operators I don't think I fully understand it?

Comment: Have a look at: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: @DieterLücking That doesn't answer the question?

Comment: @EdwardBird Yes it does... The bit perhaps missing for you is that expression `file << 0x52` returns a reference to `file`.

Comment: @jrok Could you explain it to me please?

Comment: Just edited the comment.

Comment: It doesn't mention anything about distinguishing between "<<" and "<<" in the 2 contexts I mentioned in my example.

Comment: Ah I see, so it follows down the chain?

Comment: @EdwardBird Combined with the fact that `<<` groups left to right (as you can see in the table that Dieter linked to), yes.

Comment: How does operator precedence answer his question about how C++ parses an ambiguous expression?

Comment: @mrjoltcola It doesn't except for that in this example, because it goes left to right and returns an ostream object each time, it follows along the chain, left to right, sending data to file.

Answer (score 4):

Operators in C++ have a precedence and an associativity.

The expression

```
a << b << c << d
```

is interpreted (because `<<` is left-associative) as

```
((a << b) << c) << d
```

so thanks to the fact that `operator<<` for a stream returns the stream itself you get the "chained output" look.

For example the assignment operator is instead right-associative, therefore

```
a = b = c = d
```

is interpreted as

```
a = (b = (c = d))
```

Note that about using `<<` operator for streams there is a subtle fact that is often misunderstood by C++ novices. Precedence and associativity rules will only affect the result, but not the order in which the result is computed. For example in

```
std::cout << f() << g() << h();
```

it's possible that evaluation of `h()` happens before evaluation of `g()`. Even worse the idea of an evaluation order is misplaced for C++... because in

```
std::cout << f(g()) << h(i());
```

a valid sequence for the calls is also `i, g, f, h`.

Comment: Not only it's possible that `h` gets evaluated before `g`, it's actually pretty common, because the arguments for a function call get evaluated right-to-left and pushed onto the stack in that order (in order to be able to easily implement variadic functions -- the first arguments of the function, which usually tell you how many arguments to look for, are on the top of the stack). For instance, in `cout << g() << h()`, which is actually `operator<<(operator<<(cout, g()), h())`, you get `h()` evaluated before `g()` in the topmost `operator<<`.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**: from the context.

---

**Long answer**: Writing a C++ compiler is a tough task, because C++ has a complex semantic.
First of all, if `operator<<` were not overloaded for `fstream`s, that statement would be invalid.
Moreover,  we invoke `operator<<` that way due to ADL, otherwise it'd have been (that is valid too, of course)

```
std::operator<<(file, 0x52).operator<<(file, 0x49) [...]
```

Instead, if the left hand side were a builtin one, there would be no need to look into `fstream` for something like

```
friend std::ofstream& operator<<(std::ofstream&, int)*
```

*`unsigned int` could match as well

as the behavior of a left shift on a built in type (such as `unsigned int`) is well defined, while an user-defined type isn't.

In this case

```
file << (0x52 << 0x49 << 0x46 << 0x46);
```

the expression inside the parenthesis is interpreted *before* `file <<`, as it has an higher precedence than `file <<`.

Comment: `std::operator<<(file, 0x52).operator<<` It is unlikely that the second operator calls a different function (member instead of non-member). Moreover, if it were a member function, it would take only one argument.

Comment: *"the expression inside the parenthesis is interpreted before file <<, as they have an higher precedence."* That's not correct.

Comment: @jrok What do you mean? I've edited, hope it's clearer.

Comment: `( x << y << z << w)` is a single expression and a subexpression of left-shift expression of which it is a part of. It will of course be executed before `operator<<` is called, but it is wrong to say it has higher precedence - that's a compile time property (w.r.t. execution, the expression `file` can be evaluated before or after it).